# How to get the name of the objects of a class

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get the names of the `TextLine` objects of the `PageHeader` class(`textline1`, `textline2`) in a form class and display it in the form. The classes are as below

```
class Textline
{
    string text;
    string name;
}

class PageHeader
{
    TextLine textline1;
    TextLine textline2;
}
```

Comment: @jalf, there's really *no* need to be so snarky. Politeness costs absolutely nothing. Show the user how to correct their mistake, don't just rant at them for making the mistake. Not everyone knows their way round stackoverflow! =)

Comment: @Rob: I note that *you* didn't "show the user how to correct his mistake". I've done so, a few hundred times at the very least. But you don't need to "know your way around SO" to look at the *live* preview of your question, and go "hmm, my code is unreadable, I wonder if there is anything I can do about that". It is about whether you *care* enough to make your question readable to those you're asking for help from. And if you don't care about that, there is *plenty* of reason to be snarky.

Comment: @user673453: when you post a question, there is, just above the text input box, a number of buttons. One of them has a `{ }` symbol, and is used to format your code. Pretty please with sugar on top, USE IT. And just *below* the input box, it shows *exactly* what your question will look like when asked. If that is not readable, *go back and figure out how to make it so*. Don't just type in some text, close your eyes and hit "ok", and rely on *others* to make your question readable for you. Thank you.

Comment: @jalf - I didn't. But then the question was already formatted by the time I saw it, I corrected "Class" to "class", a much more trivial change =)

Comment: @Rob: so you think that because someone else has fixed the OP's question for him, there is no need to show the OP how to do it *next time*? And yet you bother to criticize *others* for not showing the OP how to do it? Interesting...

Comment: @jalf, I criticized you for being rude. There was no need for it. None of us *have* to educate new/inexperienced users; however none of us *should* be rude and snarky towards other users. By implying that I shouldn't pull you up for said snarky behaviour unless I educate the user you're conflating two entirely separate issues. "If you can't say anything nice, don't say anything at all", i.e. if you're not willing to politely and helpfully help someone, say nothing. =) (and yes, I did +1 your comment to user673453 to help draw it to their attention)

Comment: @Rob: Whichever way you do it, with sarcasm or politeness, I think educating a new user is better than doing nothing. Silently ignoring a new user's mistakes is the *worst* thing you can do, because it means the user will keep making those mistakes, and will get fewer or lower quality answers as a result. So if that's your preferred strategy, I should be the one criticizing you. ;) And like I said before, if someone asks you to help, but don't want to make the least effort *themselves* to be helped, then I think that's a reasonable reason for a bit of snarkyness.

Comment: Of course, this all relies on the pretty major assumption that we are talking about a new users *mistakes* (which said user can learn to avoid), or about a user's *laziness* and willful  arrogance in assuming that "I don't have to put any effort into my question, because others will do the hard work for me".

Comment: @jalf - if you're such a Stack Overflow hotshot why didn't you notice the user's low reputation score that clearly indicates that @user673453 hasn't used Stack Overflow much...

Comment: @Dr Rob: who said anything about being a hotshot? And the point I've been trying to make is that it's not about how much you've used SO. Even if you have **NEVER** used the site before, you should still be capable of looking at the live preview that is shown *just below* your text input box, yes? And if you can look at that, then you should also be able to recognize that "hmm, my source code is all garbled and practically unreadable".

Comment: And if you can make that observation, then, whether or not you've used SO before, you ought to be able to jump to the conclusion that "I'd better figure out a way to make it readable, because I want people to read my question and give me an answer to my problem". There is nothing in the process about "having used StackOverflow before", and nothing about being a hotshot. And I'd like to point your attention to the fact that, unsurprisingly, no one except me actually bothered to tell the user how to format his source code. You know the saying that "actions speak louder than words"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have instance `pgHead` of `PageHeader`. You can obtain name of textline1 this way:

```
pgHead.textline1.name
```

but in this sample you should add `public` key words before all members of your classes

[EDIT]
If you want to obtain only field names of PageHeader type try out reflection as below:

```
var items = typeof(PageHeader).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

string fieldsNames = "";

foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fld in items)
{
    fieldsNames += fld.Name + "\n";
}

MessageBox.Show(fieldsNames);
```

Comment: @Anton Is it possible to display the object name withou creating the instance of PageHeader

Comment: you can do this from wherever the two TextLine instances are visible. However, you will have to create them (new TextLine( "namegoeshere" )

Comment: No. Textline and PageHeader are classes, so without instantiation you havent any essence from wich you can obtain value. In other words you should create instance of PageHeader first and then create two instances of TextLine and assign they to textline1 and textline1. And dont forget to add public keyword!

Comment: @Anton Is it not possible to use Reflection to get the names of the PageHeader object in the form.

Comment: Ok, its seems that Im not clearly understand that you are trying to ask. If you are intended to investigate values of textline1 and textline2 fields of PageHeader class, in this case instantiation is inevitable. But if you are intended to obtain only names of fields of PageHeader type so in this case Reflection would be best

Comment: @Anton how is Reflection used

Answer (score 1):

If you go with Barna's answer, do not forget to set the Name property. I would introduce a matching constructor:

```
class TextLine
{
    private string text;
    private string name;

    public TextLine( string name )
    {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get {return name;}
    }
}
```

And then use it with:

```
TextLine tl = new textLine("MyName");
System.Console.Out.Writeln( "name of tl: {0}", tl.Name );
```

hth

Mario

Comment: Is it not possible to use Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need:

```
class Textline
{
    string text;
    string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } }
}
```

and then:

```
textline1.Name
```